# Why I am not able to use mocha through nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, nodemon

I am trying to run test cases using *mocha framework*. I am trying to run it through `nodemon`, but getting an error.

I have installed `nodemon` already through `npm install nodemon` and similarly with `mocha`.
How do I run my project through `nodemon` so that my test cases show the result using mocha framework?

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the Command Prompt, my test cases are not running for whatever I do with `nodemon`.

Comment: It is always recommended to copy the error directly in SO, with proper formatting. Links can expire, or point to wrong locations, or fail for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'll review my question again.

Comment: Why are you trying to use nodemon and not `mocha -w`?

Comment: @Baruch mocha is a framework used for testing test case.. while nodemon is a package which helps in running project all the time in command prompt whenever I hit save button. I am trying to run my project on nodemon and do testing through mocha but I'm not sure where I am messing up, because mocha test cases are not getting executed in command prompt through nodemon.

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul The question is why do you want to run mocha through nodemon? If you want the tests to run whenever a file changes you may use `mocha -w`as @Baruch proposed

Comment: nodemon will make sure your changes are reflected in the app youre making, mocha -w will make sure your tests are ran on save

Comment: @ThatBrianDude Yes right but i am following a tutorial and i have been told to do the same and i do not want to mess up things in the future follow-up

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul If you're following a tutorial and you came across this issue, it means the tutorial is not good, doesn't it? `mocha`, as almost any testing frameworks, provides a way to watch files using the framework's CLI. I suggest you use that.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume you have an entry like following in your package.json - 
`scripts": {
    "start:test": "mocha test/ --recursive --exit"
 }`

To run the mocha test using nodemon please use the following command: 
nodemon --exec "npm run start:test"

Answer (score 1):

```
"test": "nodemon --exec 'mocha -R min'"
```

then: `npm run test`